# Image in flex container not centering after defining width and height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm doing some personal portfolio using css flex box. what I'm trying to do is to center the image horizontally, It did center but the problem is after I defined `width` and `height` to `img` the image is at the start or left now not in the center.

This is what it looks like when centered and not defining the `width` and `height`

```css
.center-img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-img">
  <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/06560124247439e98f5534b17467b691/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png" alt="user">
  <h1>User</h1>
</div>
```

And this is what it look liked after defining `width` and `height`

```css
.center-img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-img">
  <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/06560124247439e98f5534b17467b691/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png" alt="user">
  <h1>User</h1>
</div>
```

I expect that after defining the `width` and `height` of the image it would not affect the position of the image. so it should be in the center.
thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few things to consider:

1. **You were never centering the image.**

   In your first code sample, the image was occupying the entire viewport width, so it just appeared centered. When you reduced the size of the image with `width` and `height`, it aligned left, per the default value. Use `align-items` to horizontally center flex items in a column-direction container.
2. **Don't use images as flex items. There are lots of bugs.**

   Images as flex items are known to have rendering problems across different browsers. Instead, wrap the image in a div, and make the div the flex item.
3. **Align the image inside a nested container with flex properties.**

   Use a nested flex container to center the image.

```css
.center-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.center-img > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  
}

.center-img > div > img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-img">
  <div>
    <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/06560124247439e98f5534b17467b691/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"
      alt="user">
  </div>
  <h1>User</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the height and width to the img only and add `align-items: center` like this:

```
.center-img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```
<div class="center-img">
  <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/06560124247439e98f5534b17467b691/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"
            alt="user">
 <h1>User</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrangle the dimensions of the items inside.

The image can be controlled with `max-width` and `max-height` relative to the container. I added the red border so you can see the container easier.

Also, the `h1` element comes with big `font-size` and `margin` by default so need to set values for those too.

```css
.center-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* change text-align to align-items */
  border: 1px red solid; /* this is just so you can easily see the container */
}

.center-img img {
  max-width: 100%; /* dimensions relative to the container size */
  max-height: 40%; /* dimensions relative to the container size */
  height: auto; /* keep aspect ratio */
  width: auto; /* keep aspect ratio */
}

.center-img h1 {
  margin: 5px 0 0; /* h1 has default margin-top and margin-bottom */
  font-size: 18px; /* Set this to a reasonable size */
}
```

```html
<div class="center-img">
  <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/06560124247439e98f5534b17467b691/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"
    alt="user">
  <h1>User</h1>
</div>
```